# Scope associated element with join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, activemodel

I'm trying to scope the main group of my user. This group is noted with a cat: which is 2.

So I thought of doing this with a scope like

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_group, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :users_group

  scope :my_group, -> { self.joins(:groups).where('groups.cat = 2').limit(1) } 
end
```

But the command below is not working :

> current_user.my_group

Can you lead me on the good way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mario says, a scope works on a collection, not an instance.

If you want to keep the method in the `User` model you can use the following:

**user.rb**

```
def my_group
  groups.find_by_cat(2)
end
```

Using `find_by` will return a single group, rather than using `where` / `limit`. If the group isn't found, it will return `nil`.

I'd suggest using a scope to return a single instance is a bit of an anti-pattern, and it would be better achieved using this method, or dropping the following method into `Group` and calling `current_user.groups.my_group` - although the name `my_group` sounds a bit out of place like that. For completeness, here it is regardless:

**group.rb**

```
def my_group
  find_by_cat(2)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SRack, I finally understood my mistake

Answer (score 2):

`current_user` doesn't return an ActiveRecord relation, it just returns the user so you can't chain it together with a scope (I'm assuming the error message you're getting is `undefined method 'my_group' for #<User>`?). Add the scope to your **Group** class and use it through your `groups` has_many relationship e.g.
`current_user.groups.my_group`